# Modifying form submission data before it gets sent to stringRead

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework, digestive-functors

I have a Digestive Functors form that looks like this:

```
dateTimeForm :: Monad m => Maybe LocalTime -> Form Text m LocalTime
dateTimeForm t = LocalTime
    <$> "date" .: stringRead "Must be a valid date" (localDay <$> t)
    <*> "time" .: stringRead "Must be a valid time" (localTimeOfDay <$> t)
```

The input elements I'm using for this form are `<input type="date" />` and `<input type="time" />`.  This works very well for the date portion of this form, but not so well on the time portion.  Browsers that support the time input element only submit the hours and minutes (eg. "18:00"), but a TimeOfDay requires hours, minutes, *and* seconds.  This causes stringRead to fail and Digestive Functors reports an error to the user ("Must be a valid time").

I tried working around this like so, but if the user submits an invalid time, they no longer get an attractive error from Digestive Functors (Prelude.read: no parse).

```
dateTimeForm :: Monad m => Maybe LocalTime -> Form Text m LocalTime
dateTimeForm t = toLocalTime
    <$> "date" .: stringRead "Must be a valid date" (localDay <$> t)
    <*> "time" .: string (show . localTimeOfDay <$> t)
    where
        toLocalTime d x = LocalTime d $ read $ if length x == 8 then x else x <> ":00"
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add the seconds to the `TimeOfDay` value? Looking at the [documentation for the type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.4.0.1/docs/Data-Time-LocalTime.html#v:todSec), I guess it might work (the fields for hours, minutes and seconds are exported).

Comment: This would be trivial if I were using a subform containing individual fields for hours and minutes (see: http://jaspervdj.be/posts/2012-04-03-digestive-functors-for-snap-users.html), but I'm getting a single string from the form submission containing the time.  So basically, I need to tack on the seconds as a string *before* Digestive Functors starts looking at it.

Comment: What I mean is that, given the types, something like `(addSeconds . localTimeOfDay <$> t)`, with `addSeconds :: TimeOfDay -> TimeOfDay`, should work, unless your `t` is a `Nothing` - but I guess it isn't, as your workaround mostly works. (Forgive me if this turns out to be nonsense; as I don't know digestive-functors I am just making educated guesses from the types.)

Comment: I see what you're referring to, but unfortunately no.  The `(localTimeOfDay <$> t)` represents the default value for that form.  If `t` was a `Nothing`, then it would be a blank field; a `Just a` would have whatever `a` represents be the value of that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what I was looking for is the `validate` function and a little help from `maybeRead`.  This appears to work:

```
dateTimeForm :: Monad m => Maybe LocalTime -> Form Text m LocalTime
dateTimeForm t = LocalTime
    <$> "date" .: stringRead "Must be a valid date" (localDay <$> t)
    <*> "time" .: validate validTime (string (show . localTimeOfDay <$> t))
    where
        -- the time input element only submits hours and minutes ("18:00"), which is 5 characters long
        validTime x = case maybeRead (if length x == 5 then x <> ":00" else x) of
            Just x' -> Success x'
            _ -> Error "Must be a valid time"
```